# checkbox not updating in laravel

Tags: laravel

Similar questions has been asked and i have gone through all solution but none work for me.
I dont get any error but the value doesnt not change in database.

blade view

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fenced" @checked($house->fenced)/>
<x-formlabel name="Fenced" />
```

controller

```
public function update(house $house)
    {
        $uhouse = request()->validate([
 'fenced' => ['boolean'],
]);
        
        if($uhouse['fenced'] ?? false)
        {
            $uhouse['fenced'] = 1;
        }
 $house->update($uhouse);
```

Comment: is the field `fillable`?

Comment: also what are you doing with your `if` statement? if it passed the `boolean` rule it has to be one of these values: `true, false, 1, 0, "1", and "0"`

Comment: @lagbox, it is fillable in the model. Even without the if statement, it doesn't work.

Comment: `$house->update(['fenced' => request()->has('fenced')]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have value in your checkbox! Change to this:

```html
<input value="1" type="checkbox" name="fenced" @checked($house->fenced)/>
<x-formlabel name="Fenced" />
```

I think validate doesn't return request values so just grab them yourself!
The controller

```php
public function update(house $house)
    {
        $uhouse=request()->all();
       
        $uhouse['fenced'] = !!($uhouse['fenced'] ?? false);
       
 $house->update($uhouse);
}
```

Or simply

```php
public function update(house $house){
   $house->fenced = !!(request()->input('fenced')?? False);
   $house->save();
}
```

As @legbox mentioned in comments this will work too and it's cleaner.

```
$uhouse['fenced'] = request()->has('fenced');
```

Comment: if i add value="1"in blade view, the view will not echo database value of fenced. I need the view to echo database value which has been created before editing it.

Comment: `value` is not `checked`! `value` is simply the value within! If `checked=true` then value is sent and if not,  nothing sent!

Comment: @upcoming just try and let me know

Comment: @upcoming a boolean juggled to a string only has 2 possible outputs `'' and '1'` .. so only the `true` would print anything, false is `null == ''` ... what are you expecting the value to be?

Comment: No checkbox if not checked is not included in form. And also `null == ''` is NOT TRUE at all. Did you try my answer? And it didn't work?

Comment: @lagbox, datatype is boolean, the data in database is 1 already. when i edit, want to set it to false, 0, or null whatever. But this doesnt work after unchecking it, the value in database doesnt change.

Comment: @Alijvhr, i added checked=true in view. still cant change database value

Comment: well `null == ''` in PHP that is a fact ... but if the checkbox isn't checked then it won't be submitted at all ... so the value you set to the checkbox doesn't actually matter ... the only thing you need to check is if the input exists at all in reality

Comment: @lagbox, i ddd($house), if it is unchecked, fenced is not included in the values. so do i need to use if(statement) to set the value to 0  or null before update

Comment: @upcoming i did check in my code for false and uncheck

Comment: @lagbox it was `===` actually so it was mistaken.

Comment: @Alijvhr, thanks. $uhouse['fenced'] = !!($uhouse['fenced'] ?? false); worked.

Comment: btw, `$uhouse['fenced'] = request()->has('fenced');` ... we have a method for this and it doesn't matter what the actual value is, just if it is present